# mounted “/” as “ro”, but I can still write to it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mount, ext4

Some puzzling situation. Here's what I have:

```
root@OrangePI:~# cat /etc/fstab
# OrangePI fstab
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /  ext4  defaults,ro,noatime,nodiratime  0 1
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /media/boot  vfat  defaults,ro  0 0
tmpfs /tmp  tmpfs nodev,nosuid,mode=1777  0 0

root@OrangePI:/media/boot# mount
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (ro,noatime,nodiratime)
none on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=1777)
none on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755) /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/boot type vfat (ro)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup 
(rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

I am able to create/delete files on `/`. Proof:

```
root@OrangePI:~# touch /HELLO
root@OrangePI:~# ls -la /HELLO
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 25 00:26 /HELLO
root@OrangePI:~# rm /HELLO
root@OrangePI:~# ls -la /HELLO
ls: cannot access /HELLO: No such file or directory
```

Then:

```
root@OrangePI:~# df -T /HELLO
Filesystem Type 1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root  ext4  15340028 674788  14040832   5% /
root@OrangePI:~# reboot
```

and after the reboot:

```
root@OrangePI:~# ls /HELLO:
/HELLO
```

i.e. the file persists after reboot. I also install new packages, which all persist after reboots.

The system is [OrangePI Zero](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepizero/) (RaspberryPI clone), running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

Comment: Try a `df [filename]` after touching the new files, what does it say? If you edit a new file in `/` is it still there after rebooting? I'd suspect there's a tempfs or overlayfs allowing writes everywhere, even though the on-disk filesystems are ro, but I'm not seeing it in `mount`'s output...

Comment: And the question is…? "How can it be?", "Is it safe?", "How to make it really `ro`?", "Is it a bug?", "How to do such a trick on amd64 Debian?"

Comment: @Xen2050 `touch /HELLO',  `df -T /HELLO`

`Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on`

`/dev/root      ext4  15340028 674788  14040832   5% /`

 `reboot`, `ls /HELLO`:

`/HELLO`
ie. file persists after reboot. (I am installing new packages, which all persist after reboots).

Comment: Formal note: [edit] your question to add relevant information (this time I did it for you). In a comment you can then notify any interested user that the question has been edited. The point is to have all the information in the question body.

Comment: /dev/root doesn't show up in mount's output, looks like it's rw. `/proc/mounts` very different?  Any interesting messages after `mount -vo remount,ro /dev/root` or `mount -vo remount,ro /dev/mmcblk0p2`, in terminal or dmesg / syslog?

Comment: @Xen2050: `mount: can't find /dev/root in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab` and `mount: / is busy` respectively

Comment: I have re-installed Rasbian. I am able to mount `/` as `ro` using this distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I have "installed" Rasbian (still doesn't work on `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`)

Answer (score -1):

`root@OrangePI:~#`
You are root, you can do anything. (i'm new to superuser, can't use comment)

Comment: Thanks, but see the original post.